# How to deep clone object in dot netcore

Tags: serialization, .net-core, json.net, clone, deep-copy

I'm using .Net core 2.2 and it's dependency injection. I also inject dependencies from third party libraries. I want to deep clone the object where dependencies are injected. Binary Serialization is not an option as classes from other libraries are not marked as `Serializable`. Json serialization and Reflection cloning is not working as many classes do not have default constructors.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935056/cloning-objects-without-serialization), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545025/how-to-deep-copy-a-class-without-marking-it-as-serializable) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) but not helping

How should I deep clone objects?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is related to exactly what you're issue may be, but I had same issue and it was due to how I was bringing in the DbContexts in the startup.cs file. I had to remove the LazyLoading for the connection that I was using trying to make the DeepClone. Once I did that, it went back to working as expected.

FROM:

services.AddDbContext(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbMaster"), opt => opt.UseRowNumberForPaging())
               .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()**.UseLazyLoadingProxies());**

TO:

services.AddDbContext(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbMaster"), opt => opt.UseRowNumberForPaging()).EnableSensitiveDataLogging());

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know this but I ended up using some combination of binary serialization and at places AutoMapper